# Fail2ban does not ban IP - Apache digest authentication

Tags: debian, apache-http-server

Fail2ban does not block login attempt on my web server, what's wrong?

The configuration has been reloaded, the service restarted, even the server restarted...

```
# fail2ban-client reload
# service fail2ban restart
# reboot
```

Configuration:

Output of: `uname -a`

```
Linux myWebServer 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u1 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Output of: `lsb_release -a`

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.7 (wheezy)
Release:        7.7
Codename:       wheezy
```

Output of: `apache2 -v`

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Server built:   Jul 24 2014 16:20:38
```

Output of: `fail2ban-client -V`

```
Fail2Ban v0.8.6
```

Output of: `cat /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-auth.conf`

```
[INCLUDES]

before = apache-common.conf

[Definition]

failregex = ^%(_apache_error_client)s user .* (authentication failure|not found|password mismatch)\s*$

ignoreregex =
```

Output of: `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
[...]
[Mon Nov 17 10:28:46 2014] [error] [client x.x.x.x] user bob not found: /myshare
[Mon Nov 17 10:28:51 2014] [error] [client x.x.x.x] user userTest not found: /myshare
[Mon Nov 17 10:30:37 2014] [error] [client x.x.x.x] user user1 not found: /myshare
[Mon Nov 17 10:37:35 2014] [error] [client x.x.x.x] user user2 not found: /myshare
[...]
```

Output of: `fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/error.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-auth.conf`

```
Running tests
=============

Use regex file : /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-auth.conf
Use log file   : /var/log/apache2/error.log


Results
=======

Failregex
|- Regular expressions:
|  [1] ^\[[^]]+\] \[error\] \[client <HOST>\] user .* (authentication failure|not found|password mismatch)\s*$
|
`- Number of matches:
   [1] 0 match(es)

Ignoreregex
|- Regular expressions:
|
`- Number of matches:

Summary
=======

Sorry, no match

Look at the above section 'Running tests' which could contain important
information.
```

Output of: `fail2ban-client status apache`

```
Status for the jail: apache
|- filter
|  |- File list:        /var/log/apache2/error.log
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  `- Total failed:     0
`- action
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |  `- IP list:
   `- Total banned:     0
```

Output of: `cat /etc/apache2/conf.d/usershare.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/myshare>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "myshare"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/pass
        Require User gooduser
</Directory>
```

**Edit:**

I want to ban the IP of failed client attempt: "authentication failure", "user not found" and "password mismatch". Fail2ban does not work properly as you can see with the information I provided. What am I missing? How can I ban the IP of failed client attempt in /var/log/apache2/error.log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was Issue nr 286: see here for problem description: [fail2ban apache-auth issue](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/286).

This was corrected on github, you can apply following patch, which can be found [here on github](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/commit/6ce41a611d8f4a7daf8b522ba25aa230f726ca96)

I put the solution here, too: it is to replace the failregex in apache-auth.conf file by the following:

```
failregex = ^%(_apache_error_client)s user .* authentication failure for "\S*": Password Mismatch$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s user .* not found: \S*\s*$
```